# What are the limits of "music"?

Tags: sefirat-ha-omer, music, three-weeks, performance-entertainment

During the Three Weeks, Sefira, and perhaps even year-round, listening to music is forbidden.  What constitutes music varies in its definition, but for the past century or so artists have been creating sound-based work with little or no melodic or even rhythmic content.

Would something like [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pqrt1f-taw8) be forbidden at any time?

Comment: I personally think it should be forbidden _all_ the time. But that's a matter of taste.

Comment: This is a question that will receive a very scattered myriad of sources.

Comment: I don't own this Sefer but I once found tons of info from it. It's called piske teshuvot. Look on siman 570 I believe.

Comment: @HachamGabriel It is 551:13 in the Piskei Tshuvos,and he references back to 493 for Mekoros. Will look it up when I have a chance.

Comment: @SethJ Sefardim hold it's forbidden all the time; ashkenazim hold it's okay except for kings (as it says in Shulchan Aruch and Rama at the end of the laws of 9 Av)

Comment: @Sam did you have a Chance?

Comment: @shmuelbrin , Piskei Tshuvos 493:4. It is minhag Yisroel not to listen to music during sefirah even without dancing and it is assur to break this fence and listening to a tape is included and there are those who hold singing with the mouth by itself is assur. Mekors include,Aruch Hasulchan seif 2,Igros Moshe 1:166 and 3:87,Minchas Yitzchak 1:111,Shu"t Kinyan Torah2:99,Yachave Daas 3:30,Oz Nidabru 8:58,Tzitz Eliezer 16:33:2. The Minchas Yitzchak explains that a minhag tov is like a neder and it is like an issur D'oraisa. See inside for more sources.

Comment: See R' Eliyahu Schlesinger's אלא הם מועדי for a lenient position.

Comment: Some poskim may be lenient depending on why you're listening to music. There does seem to be a difference between listening to music for therapeutic (to relax, alleviate depression) and listening for more celebratory reasons.

Comment: Listening to music all the time is forbidden?!

Comment: Halichos Shlomo quotes R. S.Z. Auerbach (by the laws of sefirah) as saying that only music that would bring one to dancing is prohibited. I assume 3 weeks has the same rule

Comment: As a side point once you have attached a link and all of this 'artist' material shows up, one may ask does the issur of shirei agavim, love songs/perverse songs apply to instrumental music? This performer is obviously a deviant with song names that convey his thought process behind his 'music', so does it get cclassified as agavim?

Comment: @Scimonster Not literally, but....13 days of yom tovim, 52 shabbatim, the "thirty-days",  equals about one out of four days out of the secular year that you can't listen to music. Even factoring in Shabbat and Yom Tov overlap at times, the percentage of time observant Jews cannot listen to music is quite significant.

Comment: Considering that they specifically allowed for drums to be used in Jerusalem for wedding processions (presumably with traditional vocal accompaniment) and may have had percussion instruments in funeral processions (to announce it's passing), it would seem (though I have no absolute proof of this) that a strong bass beat may not constitute "music" by itself without the addition of other instruments.

Comment: This is how I feel after listening to that example you gave: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7HoCKlNsolc

Comment: Who says it's ossur to listen to music during Sefira? The prohibition brought in the Shulchan Aruch is against dancing...Why can't I listen to music without dancing?

Comment: @Scimonster With few execptions, yes. See SA OC 560:3 and Taz s.k. 5 (http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x2923)

Comment: @SethJ I received a psak that, for me at least, dubstep is permitted during Bein HaMetzarim, since I think it’s absolutely horrendous.