# Can one listen to "Noisecore" during the three weeks?

Tags: music, three-weeks

There is a genere of music ("") which has no rhythm, harmony or groove called "Noisecore". Unlike the nature of [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17636/what-are-the-limits-of-music) there are actual instruments involved

Can one listen to  such music during the three weeks despite instruments being involved? Is this still called called klei zemer?

Reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XMCutgP9P5c

Comment: Still a duplicate?

Comment: EconJohn I think it's still a duplicate. The other question doesn't specifically exclude non-standard music that was made with standard instruments. cc @msh210